# Android Pixel 2 (8.1) DNS service discovery failure

Tags: android, nsd

Observing issue in discovering service of iOT device in Pixel 2.

OS 8.1 in other devices like Nexus / Pixel 1 find the serviceType with no issues.

Using NSD serviceDiscovery() , the log gets displays for Service Discovery Started. But its not finding the service (_customName._tcp.)

Has anyone faced such issue with Pixel 2 device?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Just for reference, this may be related to https://github.com/andriydruk/RxDNSSD/issues/38

I can see the mdns packets are being sent in wireshark (to udp multicast on another computer) but the Pixel2 does not seem to like them. The phones can receive the mdns queries and response for the local host but not from other hosts.

It works for me in the Pixel1 with 8.1.0 (OPM1.171019.011) but not in 
Pixel2 8.1.0 (with OPM1.171019.019). Not sure if it is Pixel 2 hardware related (unlikely) or the android version. I will be able to upgrade everything to OPM1.171019.021 in a month from now and test, but for now, I cannot upgrade my Pixel1

Comment: I think this can also be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102743/receiving-udp-broadcast-packet-at-pixel-2-and-pixel-2-xl